# Process id of parent process not showing up in ps-a command

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am writing a code in c in linux and I have to display the pid of the current process running as well as that of the parent process. I am using the ps -a command to cross-check it but it is not appearing there. Any help will be much appreciated

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 void main()
 {
  sleep(4);
  printf("The process id of the current process running is  %d\n",getpid());                              
  sleep(4);
  printf("The process id of the parent process is %d\n", getppid());
 }
```

Comment: How are you calling `ps -a`? It should work. Try `./program` and in another console run `pidof ./program`

Comment: @DavidRanieri I am using 2 terminals. I am executing the file in one terminal and running the ps -a command in the other one

Comment: @DavidRanieri it is showing only the process id of the current process, not the pid of the parent process

Answer (score 1):

`ps -a command` doesn't give you the PID of the command, you need to `grep`:

```
ps -a | grep command
```

if you don't want to use `grep` you can use

```
pidof command
```

But if you also want the PPID you need:

```
ps -ef | grep command
```